# Busqueda de registro de un id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

estoy haciendo una vista para un producto en especifico, estoy usando entity framework, yo obtengo el id para la vista, pero cuando veo los resultados solo me muestra el id. acá dejo el código para que puedan decirme que estoy haciendo mal, gracias de antemano.

controlador

```
 public ActionResult SalidaPieza(int? Id_Pieza)
    {

            ViewBag.Id_Pieza = new SelectList(db.Pieza.Where( m=> m.Id_pieza == Id_Pieza), "Id_pieza", "Nombre_pieza");

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult SalidaPieza([Bind(Include = "Id_Salida,Id_Pieza,Cantidad_Salida,Nota_Salida,Cliente_Salida,Fecha_Salida")] Salida salida)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Salida.Add(salida);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.Id_Pieza = new SelectList(db.Pieza, "Id_pieza", "Nombre_pieza", salida.Id_Pieza);
        return View(salida);
    }
```

Vista

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cantidad_Salida, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cantidad_Salida, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cantidad_Salida, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cliente_Salida, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cliente_Salida, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cliente_Salida, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id_Pieza, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id_Pieza, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id_Pieza, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Fecha_Salida, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Fecha_Salida, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Fecha_Salida, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

resultado de vista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres mostrar el nombre de la pieza no necesitas utilizar el `SelectList()` ya que esto aplica al `DropDownList`

Podrias hacer

```
public ActionResult SalidaPieza(int Id_Pieza)
{
    var pieza = db.Pieza.FirstOrDefault( m=> m.Id_pieza == Id_Pieza);

    if(pieza != null)
    {
        ViewBag.Pieza = pieza.Nombre_pieza;
    }

    return View();
}
```

entonces quedaria en el html

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pieza, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Ahora si quieres listar las piezas para su seleccion seria

```
public ActionResult SalidaPieza()
{
    ViewBag.Piezas = new SelectList(db.Pieza, "Id_pieza", "Nombre_pieza");

    return View();
}
```

y en el html

```
@Html.DropDownList("Pieza", ViewBag.Piezas, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

cuando listas un combo no deberias filtrar por un id

Answer (score 0):

Tu probelma no es la búsqueda, ya que la consulta está bien hecha, el problema es a la hora de utilizar el hellper html para pintar el select list. En vez de utilizar el Hellper `@Html.EditorFor(...)` utiliza:

`@Html.DropDownList("Id_Pieza ", null, new { @class = "form-control" })`

donde el primer parámetro es la colección que se va a mostrar, en este caso el ViewBag que mandas desde el controlador que se llama Id_Pieza.